# Как распарсить JSON массив не имеющий названия и извлечь конкретные значения?

Tags: android, json

есть такой  JSON массив

```
[{
   "id": "01",
    "blog_name": "My ShoutMeet Pune Event Experience",
    "publish_date": "12 sept 2015"
}, {
   "id": "02",
   "blog_name": "Best Practices for Writing High Quality Blog",
   "publish_date": "9 sept 2015"
}, {
   "id": "03",
   "blog_name": "AWS CloudFront WordPress Integration",
   "publish_date": "6 sept 2015"
 }]
```

java

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "цикл "+i);
            JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            Iterator key = objectInArray.keys();
            while (key.hasNext()) {
                String k = key.next().toString();

                String valueS = "Key : " + k + ", value : " + objectInArray.getString(k);


                builder.append(valueS + "\n"); 


            }

        }
```

Как можно извлекать при переборе объектов в массиве только значения ключей  "blog_name"  ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     names.add(objectInArray.getString("blog_name"));
}
```